# Visual Studio Code for Mac Docker: Error: cannot open display: :1.0

Tags: linux, macos, docker, visual-studio-code

I am trying to make a web app that can run a desktop app with screen sharing within Docker. I want to create a virtual display that I can monitor. I added `-e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY` to the devcontainer.json then when I ran Firefox as a test it gave me `Error: cannot open display: :1.0`. What should I do?

Comment: Running GUI applications in Docker is tricky, finicky, and not really that portable.  I'd suggest using exclusively a Web-based interface, or running your application outside Docker if you need a local console interface.

Comment: I want to run software that is not compiled for the web.